# Open Base Directory Cross Domain

Tags: php, iis, include, fastcgi, open-basedir

Changing the `open_basedir` directive to work with subdomains works absolutely fine on my server by simply setting the directive to:

`C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.net\subdomains\beta\httpdocs\;C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.net\httpdocs\`

However, when I try to do the same from one hostname to another, the open base directory does not work. This is what I am setting:

`C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domainOne.net\httpdocs\;C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domainTwo.net\httpdocs\`

I know that this can be quite challenging to achieve with FastCGI and PHP, but surely there is an easy fix?

I have tried giving permissions to the user of the current site, on the other sites folder but this has not worked.

The error being returned (as expected) is the following:

> Warning: include(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domainOne.net\httpdocs_snippets_global\paths.php)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domainTwo.com\httpdocs\;C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domainOne.net\httpdocs)
>   in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domainTwo.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 3
>   Warning:
>   include(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domainOne.net\httpdocs_snippets_global\paths.php):
>   failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in
>   C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domainTwo.com\httpdocs\index.php on line 3

**So my question is, how do I open the base directory cross domain on a Windows Server running IIS 7, Plesk 11 and PHP 5.3 running as FastCGI Application?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All sorted, the open base directory setting was indeed correct.

I was on the right lines with adding permissions to the user, I just added the wrong user!

**So quite simply, if you run into this, assuming this is the issue you are experiencing, just make sure the user of the website in question also has permissions on the folder and files of the included directory.**